# MTHML file can't play a video

Tags: video, mhtml

I have an MHTML file that contains a video. (that is linked to the .mp4 file)

The goal is to have the video play in the MHTML using the built-in web browser MP4 player but chrome browser keeps giving this error message:

Blocked script execution in 'filename' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set.

The file does not have any iFrames. Does anybody know how to fix this?
The video tag is like this in my MHTML file

```
<video height=3D"265" width=3D"470" controls src=3D"test.mp4"></video>
```